# How to update the status bar color also make it transparent on drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigationview

I set the action bar color dinamically.

I'm trying this way:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    float[] hsv = new float[3];
    Color.colorToHSV(color, hsv);
    hsv[2] *= 0.8f;
    color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color)
}
```

How you can see, I'm setting the action bar color and making the color darker to be setted on status bar. I don't know if this is the right way but until now it's working.

The problem is when I open the drawer the color isn't being transparent. How can I do it here?

Comment: What does  drawer mean ? Why don't you just hide it ?

Comment: drawer = navigation view/menu

Comment: Because you need use `android:fitsSystemWindow="true"` for your Drawer. `DrawerLayout` overrides status bar color then, and if you want change color you will need to use `NavigationDrawer` method. Unfortunately, I don't remember it now but name has word "bar" or "status"

Comment: Well... Then are u use a transparent status bar in the theme style?

Comment: E.g. `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`. Although, I use these settings: `<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Comment: I use all these settings less `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>`. If I use this one the color setted programatically will have no effect. However when the drawer is opened the status bar is transparent.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the following:

In Activity, which holds the toolbar, add to `onCreate()`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    int flag = getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flag | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

In styles-v21:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">#30000000</item> <!-- This is gonna make status bar darker by 20% -->
```

This should be enough for it to work.

Comment: Not working... Where do I set the color dinamically?

Comment: Well, if you are using Toolbar and set it as supportActionBar, then you should have reference to it. So just change background color of your toolbar. I mean:
`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewByID(R.id.toolbar);`
`setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`
`//change background color of toolbar`